# TexStudio, How to search regexp to the next }-bracket

Tags: texstudio, search

I have a macros in my tex-file like \tmp{#1}{#2} and I would like to replace it with, e.g., a string. 
However, if I search for `\\tmp\{.*\}\{.*\}` the search also highlights entire constructions like

> \tmp{bla}{bla} blabla. In \cite{bla}

i.e. it does not stop at the second instance of closing "}" as expected but goes to the third one.

Is it a bug or a normal behaviour please?

Regards,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `.*` is a greedy expression, which means it will match as much as possible. Try the lazy expression `.*?`, which will match as few as possible: `\\tmp\{.*?\}\{.*?\}`. However TeXStudio was already reported to not accept the lazy quantifier locally, but only as a global option: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/506904/134574

Comment: If there are never any nested {} within #1 and 'e you could use `\{[^\{\}]*\}` to match `{..}` with no `{` or `}` between them. If you actually need to step over matching braces and match things like `{zzz{vbb}zzz}` then the "regular" in "regular expressions" should mean that is not possible (although some systems provide extended syntax to match non-regular expressions)